# C# How can I paste formatted text from clipboard to the RichTextBox

Tags: pdf, c#, winforms, richtextbox, paste

I added context menu to the richboxtext with only one function "paste". What code will paste my clipboard content (e.g. copied from Microsoft Word) to the richboxtext form? I tried with:

```
    private void PasteToolStripMenuItem_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = Clipboard.GetText();
    }
```

but it pastes non-formatted text. How can I paste text with the formatting?

Comment: How about `Clipboard.GetDataObject().ToString();` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got it!

Just specificy the format:

```
richTextBox1.Text = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Rtf);
```

#### UPDATE

This will help you get formatted text(text only) from MS Word

Answer (score 5):

```
DataFormats.Format myFormat = DataFormats.GetFormat(DataFormats.Html);

if(richTextBox1.CanPaste(myFormat))
{
    richTextBox1.Paste(myFormat);
    return true;
}
```

you should change the Dataformats.Html of which type your Richtextbox should allow.

Here's the list of DataFormats : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dataformats.aspx

Comment: The problem is that richtextbox is not allowing DataFormats.Html.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
richTextBox1.selectedRtf=Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Rtf).ToString();
```