# I cannot paste formatted text into rich text box

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am upgrading an old program from windows forms to wpf. On the old windows forms app I had a RTB and I could paste text to it from a web page or visual studios and it would keep the text size color and font.

I now have a wpf rich text box but when I paste (ctrl v) text I have copied from a web page it is just the plane black text. How can I get it to behave like the old win forms one and paste the formatted text?

```
    <RichTextBox Grid.Row="1" Margin="7" Name="RichTextBox1" Background="#FFEDEAEA">
    </RichTextBox>
```

The idea is to be able to paste formatted text then save it and reload it later, and I have a felling saving and loading the formatted text will be the next issue.

Comment: did you try http://stackoverflow.com/a/9749227/1560829

Comment: Rich text box from wpf does not have a .Text property. It seems that was a win forms RTB property.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957441/richtextbox-wpf-does-not-have-string-property-text might help

Answer (score 0):

1., There is no `Text` property, but there is a `Document` one. You can receive the data from it in the codebehind by calling:

```
string text = new TextRange(RichTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, RichTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
```

2., There is an [Extended WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/), which adds the `Text` dependency property to the `RTB`.